# Making a password lock for an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, locking, passwords

I'm wanting to make a password unlock screen for my app, and I'm not sure how I'd go about it.

I'm wanting it to look like the Apple-designed version of it, which is the passcode lock setting screen.

[image]

How might I go about doing something like this, where as soon as all four digits are entered the code is immediately checked against a pre-set password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you create the view and when all the fields are set you check against the known password or you check the hash of the input passkey against the hash you have stored.

basically you have a stored password/hash and you check against that when you have all field filled in in your view.

when the password is correct (either by hash checking or password) you show your next view, otherwise you display an error saying the password is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was meaning, but I actually was wondering how I could get the boxes and make the text move between them seamlessly.

Comment: with the iphone sdk you have a callback whenever someone adds text, if you see that there is one character you set focus to the next textbox, it's as easy as that. look at http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10860-how-do-i-replicate-passcode-screen.html

Comment: Thanks for that link, looks very helpful!

Comment: Implementing [UIKeyInput Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) would also be a good idea so you can zeroize the password from the underlying data store. Zeroization is usually required by bodies such as NIST, DoD (STIGs), CIS (Security Benchmarks), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a project that replicates this perfectly.  I'm going to post this here for future reference in case anyone needs it.
https://github.com/guicocoa/pinview

[image: https://github.com/guicocoa/pinview]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another library, just in case someone is looking for something like this:
http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/abpadlockscreen

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 style Passcode. Complete functional demo with great documentation showing the different states (i.e Enable, Test, Change & Turn Off)

https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController