# password login - how?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a password lock for an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048894/making-a-password-lock-for-an-app)

hi
i am working on application and i want that when it open a view of password(like in the iphone) will popup. there is any class that have the password login like in the iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a view controller(UIViewController). In its view design the kind of UI you need in ur login screen. And use the present view controller method to display it.

Comment: there is any  ready viewcontroller that do it? because i want it will be like the iphone password login

Comment: Implementing [UIKeyInput Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) would also be a good idea so you can zeroize the password from the underlying data store. Zeroization is usually required by bodies such as NIST, DoD (STIGs), CIS (Security Benchmarks), etc.